# Android RuntimeException Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, exception, runtime

Hi everybody i'm trying to do a Unit converter but when I run it it stop and show me that

> 05-15 15:30:45.237: D/AndroidRuntime(333): Shutting down VM
>   05-15 15:30:45.237: W/dalvikvm(333): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
>   05-15 15:30:45.288: E/AndroidRuntime(333): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-15 15:30:45.288: E/AndroidRuntime(333): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.alaenvargut.conversor/org.alaenvargut.conversor.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   05-15 15:30:45.288: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
>   05-15 15:30:45.288: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
>   05-15 15:30:45.288: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>   05-15 15:30:45.288: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
>   05-15 15:30:45.288: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   05-15 15:30:45.288: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   05-15 15:30:45.288: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>   05-15 15:30:45.288: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   05-15 15:30:45.288: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   05-15 15:30:45.288: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   05-15 15:30:45.288: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>   05-15 15:30:45.288: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   05-15 15:30:45.288: E/AndroidRuntime(333): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   05-15 15:30:45.288: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1647)
>   05-15 15:30:45.288: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at org.alaenvargut.conversor.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:13)
>   05-15 15:30:45.288: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
>   05-15 15:30:45.288: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
>   05-15 15:30:45.288: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
>   05-15 15:30:45.288: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
>   05-15 15:30:45.288: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  ... 11 more

this is my main code

```
    package org.alaenvargut.conversor;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{
    public Spinner SUni = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    public Spinner SFm = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    public Spinner STo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ArrayAdapter AUni = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Unidades, android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item);
        AUni.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        SUni.setAdapter(AUni);  
        SUni.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int pos, long id) 
    {
        if (parent.getId() == R.id.spinner1) 
        {
            switch((int)id)
            {
            case(1):
            {   
            }
            case(2):
            {
              ArrayAdapter AFm = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Velocidad, android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item);
              AFm.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                SFm.setAdapter(AFm);

            }
            default: 
            }
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
    {
        // Another interface callback
    }




}
```

and this is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="@string/principal" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="@string/fm"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"
    android:text="@string/to"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="@string/con" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

and this is my xml file from values

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="Unidades">
        <item >Volumen</item>
        <item >Velocidad</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="Velocidad">
        <item >Km/h</item>
        <item >M/h</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

any idea about the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to initialize your `Spinners` after setting your layout in your onCreate() method not before that. Just try as below: ​

```
public Spinner SUni;
public Spinner SFm;
public Spinner STo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SUni = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    SFm = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    STo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
}
```